# XCode RSS Feed Won't parse properly

Tags: objective-c, ios

I followed a tutorial (which I'll link at the bottom) that I got from an old StackOverflow answer to parse an RSS feed into a UITableView. The tutorial is a bit outdated, but only a few methods were deprecated, and I replaced them with (what I hope are) the appropriate newer methods. However, I'm running into some trouble, not with the replaced methods, but with the parser not starting the parsing process. There are some NSLogs sprinkled throughout to give clues as to what is going on, and my parser isn't calling parseDidStartDocument:, it's just running and returning the last two NSLogs ("All Done!" and "stories array has %d items"). If someone could take a look at the code and tell me why it's not parsing, I would be very grateful. If you need to see some of my code, just let me know which parts you'd like to see, and I'd be happy to edit it in.

http://gigaom.com/apple/tutorial-build-a-simple-rss-reader-for-iphone/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

oooh that tutorial is way out of date - written in 2008!

Try this [tutorial](http://www.codeliscious.com/?p=784), written for iOS5 instead.

Comment: Thank you! I scoured Google for a more recent tutorial, but I guess I missed that one.